# YUM Commands getting critical error in Linux Redhat

Tags: linux, command-line, yum

Every time I run the yum command in Linux Redhat I get this error message:

```
CRITICAL:yum.cli:Config Error: Error accessing file for config file:///etc/yum.conf
```

I don't have any files regarding yum in my /etc directory. But I still seem to have yum installed since I get this message when I run "rpm -qi yum":

```
Name        : yum                          Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 3.2.29                            Vendor: CentOS
Release     : 75.el6.centos                 Build Date: Tue Jul 12 11:45:52 2016
Install Date: Tue Oct 18 16:44:21 2016         Build Host: worker1.bsys.centos.org
Group       : System Environment/Base       Source RPM: yum-3.2.29-75.el6.centos.src.rpm
Size        : 4826214                          License: GPLv2+
Signature   : RSA/SHA1, Tue Jul 12 12:13:09 2016, Key ID 0946fca2c105b9de
Packager    : CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org>
URL         : http://yum.baseurl.org/
Summary     : RPM package installer/updater/manager
Description :
Yum is a utility that can check for and automatically download and
install updated RPM packages. Dependencies are obtained and downloaded
automatically, prompting the user for permission as necessary.
virionrp@virion-rp.com [~]#
```

Any Idea why this is happening?

Comment: does `whereis yum` give you anything?

Comment: @Narzard It gives me this:
yum: /usr/bin/yum /usr/share/man/man8/yum.8.gz

Comment: is there a .conf file in that directory?

Comment: The problem is I can't even find the usr/bin directory

Comment: `$ cd /` -> `ls`  doesnt have it?

Comment: Actually I get Permission Denied

Comment: you are logged in as `virionrp@virion-rp.com` and you need to be logged in as `root@virion-rp.com`. Type `su -` and login as root to get the `root@virion-rp.com:~#` prompt then try it

Comment: When I type su - It again says I don't have permission. I'm on a web host called eHosts btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I type su - It again says I don't have permission. I'm on a web host called eHosts btw.

Are you on a shared hosting ? If yes, I think that, depending on the offer you paid for, you're not allowed to install packages.

You need to use `sudo` with yum, and if the root/admin user didn't added you to the sudoers list, then you can't install anything.